# How to download all images from url with python 2.7 - Problem

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, download

I try to download all images from 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/todayspaper' with this code:

```
import requests
from io import open as iopen
from urlparse import urlsplit

file_url= 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/todayspaper'
def requests_image(file_url):
    suffix_list = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'tif', 'svg',]
    file_name =  urlsplit(file_url)[2].split('/')[-1]
    file_suffix = file_name.split('.')[1]
    i = requests.get(file_url)
    if file_suffix in suffix_list and i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with iopen(file_name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(i.content)
    else:
        return False
```

no error occur when run it:

```
>>> 
>>>
```

but i don't know where the images downloaded in my PC?

i checked download folder and they aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download all images in the page you should:

- Download web page
- Find all image tags (`<img>`)
- Scan all image tags and find `src` attribute content
- Download all files from founded links

---

```
import os
import hashlib

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/todayspaper'

# Download page html 
page_data = requests.get(page_url).text

# Find all links in page
images_urls = [
    image.attrs.get('src')
    for image in BeautifulSoup(page_data, 'lxml').find_all('img')
]

# Clean empty links (<img src="" /> <img> etc)
images_urls = [
    image_url
    for image_url in images_urls
    if image_url and len(image_url)>0
]

# Download files
def download_image(source_url, dest_dir):
    # TODO: add filename extension
    image_name = hashlib.md5(source_url.encode()).hexdigest()

    with open(os.path.join(dest_dir, image_name), 'wb') as f:
        image_data = requests.get(source_url).content
        f.write(image_data)


for image_url in images_urls:
    download_image(image_url, './tmp')
```

Comment: thanks- it works. but when i try other url:  https://www.pinterest.com/pin/33003009752148758/?lp=true     i raise error:   IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'G:\\Users\\yaron\\Downloads\\aaa\\tr?id=130492214192672&ev=PageView&noscript=1'
>>>

Comment: To solve this issue you need to clean `image_name` from denied chars. Simplest solution is use hash from filename (like md5).

Comment: how to write in in the code? can you update the code please?